# what kind of database are used in games?

Tags: database, types

what common and popular database/(types of database) used in games?

1. MMORPG
2. browser based ,flash games
3. video games

Comment: any resources showing more in this regard?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1) As far as I know, World of Warcraft runs on Oracle RDBMS. Not sure about the implementation details, however, it seems that low priority data (like the location of a character, attribute status etc) gets dumped into database in intervals and high priority data (level, item transfer) occurs real time (hence the noticeable delay sometimes.)

Also Guild Wars uses Microsoft SQL Server but nor in RDBMS manner. They store binary data within tables that look like (char_id, last_update, data) and the game servers periodically serialize a character into a byte array, then push to DB servers. That's the same method used to transfer players between servers. Everyone is just a chunk of data.

2) As ThiefMaster said, any DB. If you see php on frontend, there is a good chance there is MySQL or PostgreSQL at the back. If you see ASP* variants, look for MS SQL Server.. Like websites.

3) Everything occurs in memory (generally.. Say, the Football Manager requires a database due to vast amounts of data processed.) A Database would just be an overkill.

Comment: I didn't think Oracle database was used in any game. definitely good to know

Answer (score 8):

1. At least WoW uses Oracle. But any good RDBMS would do the job as long as it can work with the huge amount of data.
2. Usually MySQL. But see #1 - any DB can do the job
3. No database at all - why would e.g. a game like Half-Life use a database.

Comment: Some games use SQLite for internal data management, even if they are not very data intense. I suppose this is especially true for iPhone games, if I'm not mistaken? Since the iPhone always has a SQLite client running in the background accesible to all apps.

A lot of games benefit from storing their data as JSON or XML, but simple tab-separated lists and similar solutions may also be fully adequate. I like to use JSON in my little java games I make, since I can easily include a JSON library and it potentially simplifies data management some, depending on the game.

Comment: "any DB can do the job" ? is oracle used in any browser/flash based game?. regarding 3 i just wanted to be sure  as all the game state and data is saved onto the disk.

Comment: Local-only flash games most likely don't need a DB at all. Browser games (MMOG) usually need a DB to store all the player information etc. MySQL or PostgreSQL are good enough for that.. no need to pay Oracle lots of money.

Comment: @TheifMaster That depends on how many players you believe you will end up with. If you are going to have 500 000 clients constantly querying your database you will need to have a very well-implementet database soltion. You are right though, there's no need to pay Microsoft or Oracle tons of money, but you will end up paying money for employees and so on to take care of your "free" db solution, and you may want to have a service contract with the supplier of the "free" db. Which one will be cheapest in the end will be hard to tell. Btw, another noteworthy db solution is the H2 database.

Comment: @Emanuel In any case, if you end up with 500 000 online clients simultaneously, "you" will not be thinking about databases anymore. You know, running a multi million dollar company should not be easy. Hence, both free solutions are just OK for an initial launch.

Comment: I find it odd that this answer suggests that a game like half-life would not use a database. Technically a scrap of paper is a database. In computing a text document or even an MS Word docx document is considered a database. Just presuming that when someone says "database" they mean "RDMS" is erroneous. This is not splitting hairs; this is about technical accuracy. Savegame files that you find for common desktop games are databases and I believe that that is the very information that the OP was after. Answer 3 for both of the answers here are technically inaccurate.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a list of common and popular databases/types of databases used in games:

1. Relational Databases (RDBMS) - MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite
2. NoSQL Databases - MongoDB, Cassandra
3. In-Memory Databases - Redis
4. Graph Databases - Neo4j
5. File-Based Databases - SQLite
6. Cloud Databases - Amazon DynamoDB, Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB